# marionette how to call CompositeView function from ItemView?

Tags: python, marionette

I have a function in CompositeView:

`Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
 childView: ItemView,
 onCheckMask: function() { alert('hello!') },
 ...`

I want to call this function from ItemView:

`Marionette.ItemView.extend({
 ...
 anotherFunction: function() {//here i want to call function 'onCheckMask'...}`

How I can do it?Fanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have instantiated `Marionette.CompositeView` as `myCompositeView`, simply do `myCompositeView.triggerMethod('check:mask');` in `anotherFunction()`;

This would call onCheckMask on myCompositeView. Further documentation can be found in [Marionette docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.functions.md#marionettetriggermethod).

Always prefer using events rather than calling functions directly, helps you decouple different areas in your app.